# \newcommand in class - undefined control sequence

Tags: macros, errors, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to write a class based on article.cls and I'm having some trouble with \newcommand. Here go the complete files.

Class file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
 \ProvidesClass{NITclsD}
      [2013/09/06 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class]
 \newcommand\@ptsize{}
 \newif\if@restonecol   %sem muito sentido pois é single column
 \newif\if@titlepage    %tb não tem folha para titulo
 \@titlepagefalse
 \if@compatibility\else
 \DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
 \DeclareOption{a5paper}
    {\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
     \setlength\paperwidth  {148mm}}
 \DeclareOption{letterpaper}
     {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
      \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
 \DeclareOption{landscape}
    {\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
     \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
     \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
 \fi
 \if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
 \else
 \DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
 \fi
 \DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
 \DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
 \if@compatibility\else
 \DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
 \fi
 \DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
 \DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
 \if@compatibility\else
 \DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
 \fi
 \if@compatibility\else
 \DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
 \fi
 \DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
 \DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}}
 \DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}}
 \DeclareOption{openbib}{%
   \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
       \listparindent \itemindent
       \parsep \z@
         }%
     \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
  }
 \ExecuteOptions{a4paper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final}  %mudei o tamanho da folha
 \ProcessOptions
  %______________________________________________________Inserindo os packages
  \RequirePackage[english,brazil]{babel}
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}           % Codificacao do arquivo
  \RequirePackage{cmap}             % Mapear caracteres especiais no PDF
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}          % Codificacao da fonte
  \RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
  \RequirePackage{setspace} 
  \RequirePackage{lastpage}
  \RequirePackage{parskip}
  %.............................Layout...........................
  \RequirePackage[top=3 cm, bottom=3.3 cm, left=1.5 cm, right=1.5 cm, footskip=0.5 cm]{geometry}

  %........................Figuras................................
  \RequirePackage[]{graphicx}               % Para incluir figuras (pacote extendido)
  \RequirePackage{color}                % Suporte a cores

  \graphicspath{{Figuras/}}         
  \RequirePackage{caption}          
 \RequirePackage{multicol}      
 %...........................Tabelas...............................
 \RequirePackage{array}             % Elementos extras para formata\c c\~ao de tabelas
 \RequirePackage{booktabs}              % Tabelas com qualidade de publica\c c\~ao
 \RequirePackage{longtable}             % Para criar tabelas maiores que uma p\'agina
 \RequirePackage{lscape}                    % adicionar tabelas e figuras como landscape
 \RequirePackage{multirow}
 %============================Cabeçalho e rodapé ===================
 \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
 \LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
 %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 \if@twoside
   \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
       \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
       \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
       \let\@mkboth\markboth
     \def\sectionmark##1{%
       \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection\quad
         \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\subsectionmark##1{%
      \markright {%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
          \thesubsection\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}}
\else
   \def\ps@headings{%
     \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \thesection\quad
        \fi
         ##1}}}}
\fi
\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
     \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
     \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
     \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    \let\subsectionmark\@gobble
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------------
     \if@titlepage
  \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
   \null\vfil
   \vskip 60\p@
   \begin{center}%
     {\LARGE \@title \par}%
     \vskip 3em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
       \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
   \end{center}\par
   \@thanks
  \vfil\null
   \end{titlepage}%
}
\else
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
   \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
     \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
             \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
     \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
   \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
 \if@twocolumn
   \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
   \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
\else
   \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
   \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
\fi
  \setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
  \setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
  \addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
  \@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
  \@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
  \@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
  \setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
  \setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
  \setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
  \skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
 \setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
 \setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
\renewcommand \theequation {\@arabic\c@equation}
\renewcommand \thefigure {\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
   \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
   \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
     #1: #2\par
   \else
      \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
   \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
   \DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
   \DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
   \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
   \let\l@table\l@figure
   \newdimen\bibindent
   \setlength\bibindent{1.5em}
   \let\@openbib@code\@empty
   \renewcommand\footnoterule{%
   \kern-3\p@
   \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
   \kern2.6\p@}
  %++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Definindo meus comandos
  % Definindo tamanho de fonte de se\c c\~oes e subse\c c\ões
  %v. documento www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf

 \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\small\bfseries\uppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\small\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\small\bfseries}

 \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{18pt}{10pt}[1pc] %espa\c cos para os titulos
 %----------------------------------------------Comandos necessarios para o documento
 \newcommand*{\@divisao}{}
 \newcommand*{\divisao}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@divisao}{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\@nonorma}{}
 \newcommand*{\nonorma}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@nonorma}{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\@dataaprov}{}
 \newcommand*{\dataaprov}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@dataaprov}{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\@nrevisao}{}
 \newcommand*{\nrevisao}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@nrevisao}{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\@titulonit}{}
 \newcommand*{\titulonit}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@titulonit}{#1}}
 %++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 \def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
 \setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
 \setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
 \pagestyle{plain}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \if@twoside
 \else
   \raggedbottom
 \fi
 \if@twocolumn
   \twocolumn
   \sloppy
   \flushbottom
 \else
   \onecolumn
 \fi
 \endinput
 %
 % End of file `NITclsD.cls'.
```

The tex file (I would like to put all these "usepackages" in the .cls file),

```
\documentclass{NITclsD}
\usepackage{enumitem}               % Cria listas numeradas
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}          % Formato dos titulos
\usepackage{subfig}             % Criar figura dividida   em subfiguras
\usepackage{natbib}             % Bibliografia
%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\divisao{DIVISAO}       
\nonorma{001}       %tres digitos
\dataaprov{08/2013} % formato MM/AAAA
\nrevisao{00}       %dois digitos
\titulonit{T\'ITULO}
 %:::::::::::::::::::::::
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}    
%%redefinindo o espa\c camento entre linhas do sum\'ario: sem espa\c co
\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\noaddvspace}
%
\renewcommand*\contentsname{SUM\'ARIO}
%
\small\tableofcontents
 \vspace{1em}
%-----------------testezinho
 \addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{10pt}}
%
 \section{Objetivo}
 \label{1}
 %
 %Here comes the text.
 \bibliography{referencias}
 \end{document}
```

I still have some errors related to the original article.cls, but I'd like to eliminate the "undefined control sequence" related to the \newcommand. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, report the whole error message that you find in the log file

Comment: \dataaprov{08/2013} % formato MM/AAAA

Comment: !Undefined control sequence. l.22\dataaprov{08/2013} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have mispelled it (e.g.,'\hobx'), type '|'and the correct spelling (e.g., '\hbox'). Otherwise just continue and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: Please, add the code to your question, where it can be properly formatted as the original.

Comment: Sorry, but the class is badly written.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're first defining a lot of things that are normally defined in `article.cls`, like for instance `\@ptsize`, and later on you `\LoadClass{article}`.  What I'm getting is a `LaTeX Error: Command \@ptsize already defined`, which I find reasonable.

I agree with @egreg that your class is badly written.  You may want to consult e.g. `acmconf.cls` to see how you can customize `article.cls` in your class.

Comment: I've tried to take \@ptsize out of the cls file. But log file showed an error message in which \@ptsize was missing. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I was trying to modify article.cls and besides defining \newcommand for some data, I just took repeated things off and, hence, it got baddly writen. Maybe the .cls you suggested can help.

Comment: @awel.llwyd Taking a copy of `article` and modifying it is IMHO a bad idea (as long as the differences are rather small resp. you are mainly extending `article`). Better load `article` within your class and re-define macros etc. to implement your changes. See `clsguide` for details.